# Problem with ArrayList and Stream... I have to stream an ArrayList with elements that have attributes in another ArrayList

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the Lists  and   ... Now , I have to stream the order list with the products and their names and numbers. I will write a simplified code cause the actual one is pretty long

```
ArrayList<Order> order = new ArrayList<>();
order.add(new Order(011, 579, 1 , true);

ArrayList<Product> prod = new ArrayList<>();
prod.add(new Product(9918, "Nvidia Graphic Card", 1299);
```

the goal is to stream the order with the true boolean (which in this case means is confirmed) and with the name and number of the products in those orders....

```
order.stream().filter(e-> e.isConfirmed()).forEach((v) -> System.out.println("\n \t "+ v));
```

but this is just the order, I do not know how to get the product inside the same stream... Thanks

Comment: Given your example, I don’t see any connection between the `Order` object and the `Product` object, so neither do I how to get the product inside the same stream. It would need an explicitly specified common property. By the way, `011` denotes an octal number matching the decimal number `9`.

Comment: Is `579` the product number like `9918`?

Comment: that is the order number, yes, sorry, they have the same order number which is defined by the product ID... I wrote it randomly, now I noticed.... but in my class those two numbers are the same

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this, but be warned that it is terrible ineffective solution as for each confirmed order it has to scan products list to find the valid product.
Therefore I would **strongly** recommend you to consider using another data structure (like `Map<Integer, Product>` which reduces complexity of finding a product from [O(n) to O(log n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) to store products or change the `Order` class to store `Product` (or even `List<Product>`) directly instead of storing the `productId`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            new Order(1, 1, 5, false),
            new Order(2, 2, 5, true),
            new Order(3, 3, 7, true),
            new Order(4, 1, 1, true),
            new Order(5, 2, 3, true),
            new Order(6, 3, 5, false)
    ));

    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            new Product(1, "Product 1", 1.99),
            new Product(2, "Product 2", 2.99),
            new Product(3, "Product 3", 3.99)
    ));

    String confirmedOrders = orders.stream()
            .filter(Order::isConfirmed)
            .map(order -> products.stream()
                    .filter(product -> product.getId() == order.getProductId())
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(getOrderSummaryString(order))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "Invalid product id (#" + order.getProductId() + ") in order #" + order.getId()))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

    System.out.println("Confirmed orders list:" + System.lineSeparator() + confirmedOrders);
}

private static Function<Product, String> getOrderSummaryString(Order order) {
    return product ->
            "\t Order #" + order.getId() + " of " + order.getQuantity() + " * " + product.getName() +
                    " ($" + product.getPrice() + ")," + " $" +
                    String.format("%.2f", product.getPrice() * order.getQuantity());
}
```

Output:

```
Confirmed orders list:
     Order #2 of 5 * Product 2 ($2.99), $14.95
     Order #3 of 7 * Product 3 ($3.99), $27.93
     Order #4 of 1 * Product 1 ($1.99), $1.99
     Order #5 of 3 * Product 2 ($2.99), $8.97
```

**[Live demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/1ShY)**